# High performance computing memory

Tags: memory

"a smaller main memory per node may reduces the amount of computation a node can
execute without internode communication, increases the frequency of communication, and reduces the sizes of the respective messages communicated."

I don't understand this sentence above, could you help me explain it or restate it again?

Comment: My take is: the more memory you have, the more stuff you can put in it. If you run out of memory, you'll need to "send" your information to other node.

Answer (score 1):

This clearly refers to distributed computing.

> a smaller main memory per node may reduces the amount of computation a node can execute without internode communication,

The less memory a node have, the less data it holds and less work generally have to be done on this data. The more memory it haves, the more work it has to do before synchronizing the other nodes to request more work or send the result in order to achieve some greater common deduction.

> increases the frequency of communication,

When less memory is available, the node will have to request smaller work chunks (because it can't hold any more data), and thus, have more requests.

> and reduces the sizes of the respective messages communicated

When less memory is available, the node's work chunks are smaller and thus the size of the messages carrying this work will be smaller.

### For example

Let's assume you want to do a distributed "grep" on a file with 1,000 lines, on a cluster with 2 machines.

#### First Scenario

If the machines have the capacity of 1 line, then each machine will have to communicate 500 messages (send and return).

#### Second Scenario

If the machines have the capacity of 500 lines, then each machine will receive one message of size 500, but will return a single message with all the lines that contain the requested word.

The first scenario had less computation per communication, had a higher frequency of message passing, but smaller messages to send/receive.